# Robotframework RIDE AutoIt control to press Stop

Tags: automation, autoit, robotframework

I am trying to use AutoIt to activate a running RobotFramework RIDE window and press the stop button. When using the AutoIt info tool I find that the Stop button is located within a toolbar. I have pasted the output from that tool here:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  RIDE - Security
Class:  wxWindowClassNR
Position:   665, 0
Size:   935, 860
Style:  0x16CF0000
ExStyle:    0x00000100
Handle: 0x0002052E

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  ToolbarWindow32
Instance:   1
ClassnameNN:    ToolbarWindow321
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 
Text:   
Position:   304, 79
Size:   615, 28
ControlClick Coords:    45, 14
Style:  0x52001101
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x0003047A

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   1022, 143
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xB6DBEE

>>>> StatusBar <<<<
1:  

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<
1:  145 Start
2:  146 Stop
3:  147 Pause
4:  148 Continue
5:  149 Next
6:  150 Step over
```

From this output it can be seen that the Stop button has a Command ID 146.

In terms of an AutoIt script I am trying the following:

```
WinActivate("RIDE - Security")
ControlClick("[CLASS:wxWindowClassNR]", "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]", "Start")
```

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On ToolbarWindow32 controls you usually have to use ControlCommand with the SendCommandID option. This should work for you.

```
$hWinHandle = WinGetHandle("RIDE - Security")

;make sure we have focus
ControlFocus($hWinHandle, "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]")

;uses the ControlCommand to access the stop
ControlCommand($hWinHandle, "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]", "SendCommandID", "146")
```